# Nexus repository managment using pom.xml

Tags: spring, spring-boot

how can I use the jar added pom.xml to the nexus managment repository Thanks ?

This my nexus jar

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus</id>
     <url>https://xxxxx/service/rest/repository/browse/xxxx/ee/cyber/xxxxx/2.1.5/xxxxx-2.1.5- 
        sources.jar</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

But not working in pom.xml this code block NOT !!! PROJECT WORKING IN DEPLOY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add Maven dependency for the artifact like below -

```xml
<dependencies>
<!-- Other dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xxxx.ee.cyber</groupId>
        <artifactId>xxxxx</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- Other dependencies -->
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Assuming that you have configured Nexus as your repository, Maven will take care of downloading the dependency from Nexus.